# Изменить видимость элемента в ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Пишу свое приложение под андроид и возникла следующая проблема. В мой `ViewPager` добавляются элементы, содержащие фото(`ImageView`) и NavBar, который изначально невидимый, но при клике по изображению должен становиться видимым. `Onclick`, судя по логам, обрабатывается, но `NavBar` не становится видимым. С чем это может быть связано ?

Вот код, в котором создаются и добавляются элементы `ViewPager`(`bnv` - `NavBar`):

```
for (File f: list){
        if (f.getAbsolutePath().contains(".png") || f.getAbsolutePath().contains(".jpg") ||f.getAbsolutePath().contains(".jpeg") ){
            page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
            imView = (PhotoView) page.findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
            bnv = page.findViewById(R.id.test);
            imView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(f.getAbsolutePath()));
            imView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if( bnv.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE ){
                        bnv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else{
                        bnv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                }
            });
            pages.add(page)};
```

Вот разметка page.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_item_background_colors"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main"/>

<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:id="@+id/photo_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-1dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
```

P.S. Может это как-то быть связано с тем, что я использую необычный ImageView ? Я использую [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) для возможности зумить фотографии.

Comment: покажите вашу разметку `xml`

Comment: @Jarvis_J добавил её в вопрос

Comment: если `onClick` обрабатывается, дело не в нём. Возможно у вас `menu`  пустое. Если в `xml` убрать невидимость `bvn` появится?

Comment: @Jarvis_J появляется, но меню не пустое точно, потому что я такое же меню использую в другой активити

Comment: вынесите определения всех сущностей из инициализации пейджера, сделайте управление в самом вью, а не в пейджере.